# Sending an email via an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently working on an android project and I am adding a preference to be able to send me an email. I am using the `ACTION_SENDTO` intent to send the email but its coming back and says `No apps can perform this action`.

Below is the code I am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "someone@example.com");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out this android app");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out this new app in the Google Play Store. Its from Boardies IT Solutions and is called Boardies Password Manager. You can find it at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BoardiesITSolutions.PasswordManager");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Are you trying in emulator or real device?

Comment: Its on a real device. Have gmail installed on it as well

Comment: Did you sign in before sending the email?

Comment: Gmail is setup on my device its the email client i use all the time

Comment: Try putting the following code instead of `startActivity`: `startActivityForResult(Intent, REQUEST_SEND_MAIL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following

> intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + "email@bla.com")); // leave
>   blank if not specificity

Comment: I thought using ACTION_SEND shows apps that aren't email clients such as Facebook and twitter etc, that's why I chose ACTION_SENDTO as I thought this would only show email clients.

Comment: Answer revised, this brought up the gmail application for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Worked great

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` to `Intent.ACTION_SEND`,
Hope this will work for you.

How about this code:

```
final Intent emailLauncher = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailLauncher.setType("message/rfc822");
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "username@domain.com");
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "check this subject line");
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hey check this message body!");
try{
       startActivity(emailLauncher);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

}
```